# How to obtain OracleConnection with JNDI look-up

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc, spring-boot, jndi

In my spring Boot application, I implemented this class to call stored procedure. One of the input parameters of this stored proc is an array. In order to pass in an array, OracleConnection is needed. Here is the code that does that:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class FmTrfUtil {
    static int returnVal;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    public int insertFmTrfs(List<String> trfs, String source) {    
        Session session = em.unwrap( Session.class );
        final String[] trfArray = trfs.toArray(new String[trfs.size()]);
        final String src = source;
        session.doWork( new Work(){
            public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement stmt = null;               
                OracleConnection oraCon = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
                Array array = oraCon.createARRAY("VARCHAR2_TAB_T", trfArray);
                stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call FM_TRF_UTIL.process_fm_trf(?,?)}");
                stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
                stmt.setArray(2, array);
                stmt.setString(3, src);
                stmt.execute();
                returnVal = stmt.getInt(1);
            }
        });
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

It works fine when testing in IDE where jdbc connection is explicitly specified in Spring profile (application.properties). However when I deployed the war on our dev server with jndi lookup for datasource, I got the error `java.sql.SQLException: Object does not wrap anything with requested interface` at this line `OracleConnection oraCon = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);`. This may indicate `Connection` instance is not valid. Other rest calls which does not need `Connection` still work though which means jndi is really working.

The datasource is set up in context.xml of the tomcat 7 as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context crossContext="true">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
              name="jdbc/ristoredb" password="ristoreowner987" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="ristore_owner"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://mdaoid.xxx.org:389/risdev3,cn=OracleContext,dc=ac,,dc=org"
            />
</Context>
```

I have the jndi name configured in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/ristoredb
```

It seems like obtaining jdbc Connection does not work with JNDI. What is the correct way to retrieve a OracleConnection? If this does not work, is there any alternative to pass array into Oracle stored procedure?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: any reason not to use `java.sql.Connection.createArrayOf`? You won't need the Oracle-specific code in your application.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I did `Array array = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR2_TAB_T", trfArray);` and got the error `SqlExceptionHelper   : Unsupported feature`

Comment: :( Are you using the latest available version of the JDBC driver? If so, I'd file a support ticket to get that fixed. Using the JDBC driver's API directly is very ugly.